# C++ XML Parser for Cocos2dX

Tags: xml, cocos2d-x

I am looking to port a Cocos2d game to Cocos2dx. The Cocos2dx team has used TBXML for parsing XML data ? Now is there a C++ port for TBXML. What other C++ libraries would anyone refer for parsing XML documents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the few XML Parsers Libraries in C++.

1. [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/index.htm) - DOM-style small parser  Entire library is contained in a single header file,and requires no building or configuration. A concise online manual including examples is  available.
2. [expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) - Very fast, low level XML parser for small or embedded applications
3. [PugiXML](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/) - Low memory consumption, high parsing speed,error-ignorant, includes a short documentation page including some code samples that illustrate the use of the library
4. [XmlLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/07/04/Xml/default.aspx) - High performance, lightweight from Microsoft, includes high quality documentations and articles

Reference: http://lars.ruoff.free.fr/xmlcpp/